# Conditonal Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A and B are events in a sample space with $p(A) > 0$ and $p(B) > 0$. Write $p(A|B)$ for the conditional probability of $A$ given that $B$ has occurred.

1)  If $p(A|B) < p(A)$, show that $p(B|A) < p(B)$

2)  Show that $p(A|B) ≥ \frac{p(A)+p(B)-1}{p(B)}$

For the first part:
I subbed P(B|A) < P(B) into P(B|A)= P(A and B)/P(A) to get P(A and B)/P(A) < P(B) so basically P(A and B) < P(B). I think that is the correct way for part 1 but need confirmation if possible and i'm not quite sure how to start part 2.
Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be best if you would try it on your own and ask a specific question when you get stuck. What have you got so far?

Comment: I am just confused on how to start this to be honest. ofcourse we are going to have to use the conditonal probabilty rule but do we also have to maybe add another rule with this and make it into 1?

Comment: Confusion is a normal thing. One thing you can do is to write the equations that you learned about conditional probability. Put them in front of yourself and look for similarities. Another thing that may help is thinking of examples. Have you tried Bayes rule?

Comment: I haven't tried the bayes rule but i think i got part 1 done but i'm not to sure how to start part 2

Comment: Please, add what you have.

Comment: For the first part i subbed P(B|A) < P(B) into P(B|A)= P(A and B)/P(A) to get P(A and B)/P(A) < P(B) so basically P(A and B) < P(B). I think that is the correct way for part 1 but need confirmation if possible and i'm not quite sure how to start part 2

Comment: Hint: Given that $P(A)>0$ and $P(B)>0$, you can multiply or divide by one of those without changing the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, Start with what you know: $P(A|B) < P(A)$ and $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

So do a bit of substitution and see what you get:

$$\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} < P(A)$$

You might notice something there that you can work with. Remember the formula for $P(B|A)$.

Comment: There is a typo in your solution: $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$

Comment: @hhsaffar Edited.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip I am starting to get it now. So we know that p(a|b) = P(a and b)/(p(b) and you subbed it into your second part. so with p(b|a) = p( a and b)/p(a) .... we subbed that into p(b|a) < p(b) and we get p(a and b)/p(a) < p(b)

Answer (score 0):

1. If $P(A/B)<P(A)$ then $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}<P(A)$ then $P(A\cap B)<P(B)P(A)$ and dividing by $P(A)$ to get  $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}<P(B)$. Thus, $P(B/A)<P(B)$.
2. Since $P(A\cup B)\leq 1$ then $P(A)+P(B)-(A\cap B)\leq 1$, this implies $P(A)+P(B)-1\leq (A\cap B)$. Dividing by P(B) to get $\frac{P(A)+P(B)-1}{P(B)}\leq \frac{(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, which gives the result.